# Ruby, calling method from a super

Tags: ruby

I'm a java developer just getting into Ruby. I'd like to do something like the following:

```
class A
  def foo
    print "foo"
  end
end

class B < A
  loop do
    foo
    sleep 0.5
  end
end
```

However Ruby acts like the foo method doesn't exist, I get this error:

```
Test.rb:9:in `block in <class:B>': undefined local variable or method `foo' for B:Class (NameError)
    from Test.rb:8:in `loop'
    from Test.rb:8:in `<class:B>'
    from Test.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

I actually cannot find anywhere that explains this.

EDIT: Ok, thanks but if I wanted to do something like:

```
class A
    @r = Random.new()
    def foo
        print @r.rand(0...7)
    end
end

class B < A
    def bar
        foo
        sleep 0.5
    end
end

b = B.new()
loop do
    b.bar
end
```

I get an error like:
Test.rb:4:in `foo': private method`rand' called for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from Test.rb:10:in `bar'
    from Test.rb:17:in`block in '
    from Test.rb:16:in `loop'
    from Test.rb:16:in`'

Why doesn't ruby inheritance allow this?

Comment: there's just some random loop in the b class... should that be in a method?

Comment: @Anthony Indeed it should

Comment: It isn't clear from the question whether you want to use `foo` as an instance or class method, because the code is half-way between the two. So you have answers that solve for both. Maybe worth clarifying which you intended.

Comment: Your edit is really a second question, too much has changed. Please don't use edits to your questions as an attempt to hold a back and forth conversation on multiple issues. Instead, remove your edit, clarify your first question (i.e. are you trying to create instance methods or class methods), and select the correct answer. *Then* ask your new question about access to the class variable by clicking on the "Ask Question" link

Answer (score 3):

In the code above, `foo` is called as a class method, during the class definition of B, which is why you get an error: your `foo` method is an instance method

You probably meant to do something like

```
class B < A
  def bar
    loop do
      foo
      sleep 0.5
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I think its because in java everything is within a class, but with ruby your main code is outside a class?

Comment: @DanSweeney, you just didn't put the code in a method. In java you can't do `class Test { while(true) callSomeMethod(); }`. How did java confuse you in this case?

Comment: Because I just set up this little test case and had the loop within the B class because I thought you could do that in Ruby. In java you would call one method from your main method which does the loop. But your main class would extend A.

Comment: @DanSweeney, actually you can do that in ruby. You just have to create an instance (just as in java): `class B < A; b = new; loop { b.foo; sleep 0.5 }; end`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you've defined `foo` as an instance method, not a class method.

It'll work this way.

```
class A
  def self.foo
    print "foo"
  end
end

class B < A
  while true
    foo
    sleep 0.5
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You are basically looping inside the body of the `B` class. I don't see how being a java developer confused you as in java you can't do anything like that.

Since you brought up *"calling method from super"*, I'm guessing you wanted to overwrite the `foo` method in `B` to infinitely call `A#foo` and sleep:

```
class A
  def foo
    print "foo"
  end
end

class B < A
  def foo
    loop do
      super
      sleep 0.5
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I just set up this little example as part of something more complicated, but you are right yes, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your code here reciver for **foo** is the class itself.

```
class B < A
  loop do
    foo
    sleep 0.5
  end
end
```

You shoud call your loop inside an instance method, like this

```
class B < A
  def bar
    loop do
      foo
      sleep 0.5
    end
  end
end
```